# Is there any way to include a header file in all C or CPP file automatically?

Tags: c++, c, unix, gcc, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include header file through makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346935/how-to-include-header-file-through-makefile)

I am using gcc for compiling my code. I have a few make files also. Can I tell the compiler to include a particular header file to be automatically included in the all CPP files.

How can I do this?

Comment: It makes oh so much more sense to put those into a header called `feature_support.h` or something and include that in every file that needs it.

Comment: @chris : I have seen this process automated in large code bases. But cant rememeber how it was done... :)

Comment: If you need it in every file, there may be a problem with your design.

Comment: @peter : I don't need it in every file. But it will be great if it has visibility in every file...

Comment: @NeonGlow See [#ifdef considered harmful](http://www.ethernut.de/pdf/ifdefs.pdf). That said, they do suggest if you use `#ifdef` you should do it by feature rather than, for example, system architecture. They explore other, better ways to organise code.

Comment: @Wood : I think most of the points in the shared link are applicable for #if, not #ifdef.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the appropriate [preprocessor option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) for `gcc` to your `Makefile`-s and have a `common_feature_header.h` header file defining these.

```
 # in Makefile
 CPPFLAGS+= -include common_feature_header.h
```

If you just want to define some preprocessor flags, you don't need a `common_feature_header.h` file, but simply add into your `Makefile` the following definition

```
 CPPFLAGS+= -DSOME_FEATURE_FLAG=1 -DSOME_OTHERFEATURE_FLAG=0 \
            -DYET_ANOTHER_THING=2
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495646/841108).

P.S. You may want to use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (notably with its `-x` option) to debug your `Makefile`.

Comment: Thanks... I'm new to make files. So I will appreciate a little more help understanding this. From what you said, I understand that I need to define each variable from the header file in make file also, say if I have 10 #defines in common_feature_header.h I need corresponding 10 entries in make file. Is that correct? [Sorry for asking a probably stupid question]

Comment: No, you can have several `-Dxxx` options, on the same `CPPFLAGS=`... setting in your `Makefile`

Answer (score 1):

In the makefile itself directly, you can do a `-DFEATURE1_SUPPORTED=1` for it to take effect on all CPP's using it.

Refer to the SO question: [Is it possible to define a C macro in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302390/is-it-possible-to-define-c-macro-in-makefile)

Comment: Thanks. From the link I understand, I need to add CFLAGS=-D FEATURE1_SUPPORTED=1. Is it?