# Using eclipse to edit C++ code. How do I automatically include a default header file without editing all the code

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, include, header-files

I have some existing C++ code that I am editing under eclipse Oxygen. It is reporting errors in the IDE because the original project under a different IDE was configured to include a specified default header file automatically. How can I do this in eclipse.

Not asking how to change a template for a new file.

Do not know how to use -include option as I do not have a make file. Using -include is described in "[Is there any way to include a header file in all C or CPP file automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639928/is-there-any-way-to-include-a-header-file-in-all-c-or-cpp-file-automatically) "

I cannot see a way to do this under Preferences > C/C++ Build > Settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To configure the include path in Eclipse CDT :

- Open the *Properties* dialog for your project :
  In *Project Explorer* panel, right-click on your project and in the context menu select `Properties`.
- Go to the *Build Settings* for Compiler :
  In dialog *Properties*, select `C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Compiler > Includes`
- Add an *Include file* (-include) :

  - You may select `Configuration: [All configurations]` to add the -include option both in Release and Debug mode.
  - You may create a variable in `C/C++ Build > Build Variables` to use it in the file name (e.g.: "${INSTALL_HOME}/include/global.h")

Comment: Under "C/C++ Build > Settings >" I do not see "Tool Settings". I do not see [All configurations] or a place to add -include.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are not building you code with Eclipse but just using the editor, 
and the C++ project was probably created with a type `Makefile project` without any Toolchain.
In that case I would suggest the following ...

To configure the include path in Eclipse CDT **without any toolchain** :

- Open the *Properties* dialog for your project :
  In *Project Explorer* panel, right-click on your project and in the context menu select `Properties`.
- Go to *Paths and Symbols* :
  In dialog *Properties*, select `C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes > Languages = C++`
- Add the *Include directory* that contains the header file.
- Rebuild the Index : 
  In _Project Explorer, right-click and select `Index > Rebuild`.

Comment: The source is expecting an include file to be automatically included. There is no explicit #include in the code. (Not ideal I know) I do not know how to add this file. There may be a way of prefixing all files with some code. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: In that case, instead of going to _Paths and Symbols_ use this :       (2) In dialog _Properties_, select `C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include etc. > Entries > Languages = C++ > Setting Entries = CDT User Setting` 
(3) Click Add, select _Include file_ and give the path of the header file.