# Linux: Including header files through make instead of #include in c

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a macro which is used in `afile.c` and `bfile.c` (both in module A)
This macro is in `aheader.h`

Both of these are in different modules/directories and aheader.h module is complied before module A is complied.

Now one way is to do `#include "aheader.h"` in each of the .c files.
But instead of doing this, is there a way to make some addition in the Makefile (like adding it to the list of headers) for module A, 
so that `aheader.h` is picked for everywhere the macro is used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346935/how-to-include-header-file-through-makefile

Comment: `aheader.h` is not compiled. it is a header, it can only be `#include`d.

Comment: @Jeyaram, close, but not exact duplicate, because he want to include only when the macro is used.

Comment: The real question is: *why* do you need such feature?

Comment: We have a multi-platform code base that we are trying to compile after integrating a new functionality. And since this macro is required in many places, it was thought to be better to just include it via make

Comment: If you use a marco you have created in a header, always include that header. A subsequent programmer on the project hasn't got a clue where to look where that macro came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include "aheader.h"` is the simple and correct thing to do. C has no feature to auto-include headers when a macro is used.

If you insist on doing it in the makefile, you can add `-include aheader.h` as a compilation flag. It will include it in all files.

It's possible to use the makefile to add this flag only when the macro is found in the C file, by using `grep`. But it's complicated makefile work, and I think you're better off without it.

Comment: I agree it is better to do a #include. But i just wanted to get my basics clear

Comment: So would it be something like: CFLAGS + = -include aheader.h

Comment: Yes, though this will apply to all files. Doing it for those which use the macro is significantly more complicated.

Comment: One question: CFLAGS += -include aheader.h bheader.h   when i do this, it does not pick bheader.h? could you please help

Comment: `-include aheader.h -include bheader.h`. The way you did it, `bheader.h` was unrelated to the `-include` parameter.